# How to draw only visible part of the tilemap on js canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I created simple tilemap using Tiled (3200 x 3200 pixels). I loaded it on my canvas using [this library](https://github.com/storrdev/Tiled-JSON-Canvas)

I draw entire tilemap 3200 x 3200 60 times per seocnd.
I tried to move around and it works fine. Btw, I move around canvas using **ctx.translate**. I included this [in my own function](https://github.com/danmoop/moople.js---html5-library/blob/master/Moople.js#L591)

But  when I created bigger map in Tiled ( 32000 x 32000 pixels ) - I got a very freezing page. I couldn't move around fast, I think there was about 10 fps

So how to fix it? I have to call **drawTiles()** function 60 times per second. But is there any way to draw only visible part of the tile? Like draw only what I see on my screen (0, 0, monitorWidth, monitorHeight I guess)

Thank you

Comment: What about creating 10 maps instead?

Comment: can you provide the working example as I couldn't able to run current version https://github.com/storrdev/Tiled-JSON-Canvas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##Drawing a large tileset

If you have a large tile set and only see part of it in the canvas you just need to calculate the tile at the top left of the canvas and the number of tiles across and down that will fit the canvas.

Then draw the square array of tiles that fit the canvas.

In the example the tile set is 1024 by 1024 tiles (`worldTileCount = 1024`), each tile is 64 by 64 pixels `tileSize = 64`, making the total playfield 65536 pixels square

The position of the top left tile is set by the variables `worldX`, `worldY`

###Function to draw tiles

```
// val | 0 is the same as Math.floor(val)

var worldX = 512 * tileSize;  // pixel position of playfield
var worldY = 512 * tileSize;

function drawWorld(){
  const c = worldTileCount; // get the width of the tile array
  const s = tileSize;       // get the tile size in pixels

  // get the tile position
  const tx = worldX / s | 0;  // get the top left tile
  const ty = worldY / s | 0;

  // get the number of tiles that will fit the canvas
  const tW = (canvas.width / s | 0) + 2;  
  const tH = (canvas.height / s | 0) + 2;

  // set the location. Must floor to pixel boundary or you get holes
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,-worldX | 0,-worldY | 0);  

  // Draw the tiles across and down
  for(var y = 0; y < tH; y += 1){
     for(var x = 0; x < tW; x += 1){
         // get the index into the tile array for the tile at x,y plus the topleft tile
         const i = tx + x + (ty + y) * c;

         // get the tile id from the tileMap. If outside map default to tile 6
         const tindx = tileMap[i] === undefined ? 6 : tileMap[i];

         // draw the tile at its location. last 2 args are x,y pixel location
         imageTools.drawSpriteQuick(tileSet, tindx, (tx + x) * s, (ty + y) * s);
     }
  }

}
```

###setTransform and absolute coordinates.

Use absolute coordinates makes everything simple.

Use the canvas context `setTransform` to set the world position and then each tile can be drawn at its own coordinate.

```
   // set the world location. The | 0 floors the values and ensures no holes
   ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,-worldX | 0,-worldY | 0);
```

That way if you have a character at position 51023, 34256 you can just draw it at that location.

```
   playerX = 51023;
   playerY = 34256;
   ctx.drawImage(myPlayerImage,playerX,playerY);
```

If you want the tile map relative to the player then just set the world position to be half the canvas size up and to the left plus one tile to ensure overlap

```
   playerX = 51023;
   playerY = 34256;

   worldX = playerX - canvas.width / 2 - tileWidth;
   worldY = playerY - canvas.height / 2 - tileHeight;
```

###Demo of large 65536 by 65536 pixel tile map.

At 60fps if you have the horses and can handle much much bigger without any frame rate loss. (map size limit using this method is approx 4,000,000,000 by 4,000,000,000pixels (32 bit integers coordinates))

---

#UPDATE 15/5/2019 re **Jitter**

The comments have pointed out that there is some **jitter** as the map scrolls.

I have made changes to smooth out the random path with a strong ease in out turn every 240 frame (4 seconds at 60fps) Also added a frame rate reducer, if you click and hold the mouse button on the canvas the frame rate will be slowed to 1/8th normal so that the **jitter** is easier to see.

There are two reasons for the **jitter**.

###Time error

The first and least is the time passed to the update function by `requestAnimationFrame`, the interval is not perfect and rounding errors due to the time is compounding the alignment problems.

To reduce the time error I have set the move speed to a constant interval to minimize the rounding error drift between frames.

###Aligning tiles to pixels

The main reason for the **jitter** is that the tiles must be rendered on pixel boundaries. If not then aliasing errors will create visible seams between tiles.

To see the difference click the button top left to toggle pixel alignment on and off.

To get smooth scrolling (sub pixel positioning) draw the map to an offscreen canvas aligning to the pixels, then render that canvas to the display canvas adding the sub pixel offset. That will give the best possible result using the canvas. For better you will need to use webGL

###End of update

```js
var refereshSkip = false; // when true drops frame rate by 4
var dontAlignToPixel = false;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function mouseEvent(e) {
   if(e.type === "click") {
       dontAlignToPixel = !dontAlignToPixel;
       pixAlignInfo.textContent = dontAlignToPixel ? "Pixel Align is OFF" : "Pixel Align is ON";
   } else {
       refereshSkip = e.type === "mousedown";
   }
}
pixAlignInfo.addEventListener("click",mouseEvent);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",mouseEvent);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",mouseEvent);


// wait for code under this to setup
setTimeout(() => {


  var w = canvas.width;
  var h = canvas.height;
  var cw = w / 2; // center 
  var ch = h / 2;



  // create tile map
  const worldTileCount = 1024;
  const tileMap = new Uint8Array(worldTileCount * worldTileCount);
  
  // add random tiles
  doFor(worldTileCount * worldTileCount, i => {
    tileMap[i] = randI(1, tileCount);
  });
  
  // this is the movement direction of the map
  var worldDir = Math.PI / 4;



/* =======================================================================
   Drawing the tileMap 
========================================================================*/


  var worldX = 512 * tileSize;
  var worldY = 512 * tileSize;

  function drawWorld() {
    const c = worldTileCount; // get the width of the tile array
    const s = tileSize; // get the tile size in pixels
    const tx = worldX / s | 0; // get the top left tile
    const ty = worldY / s | 0;
    const tW = (canvas.width / s | 0) + 2; // get the number of tiles to fit canvas
    const tH = (canvas.height / s | 0) + 2;
    // set the location
    if(dontAlignToPixel) {
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -worldX,-worldY);
        
    } else {
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, Math.floor(-worldX),Math.floor(-worldY));
    }
    // Draw the tiles
    for (var y = 0; y < tH; y += 1) {
      for (var x = 0; x < tW; x += 1) {
        const i = tx + x + (ty + y) * c;
        const tindx = tileMap[i] === undefined ? 6 : tileMap[i];
        imageTools.drawSpriteQuick(tileSet, tindx, (tx + x) * s, (ty + y) * s);
      }
    }

  }
  var timer = 0;
  var refreshFrames = 0;
  const dirChangeMax = 3.5;
  const framesBetweenDirChange = 240;
  var dirChangeDelay = 1;
  var dirChange = 0;
  var prevDir = worldDir;
  const eCurve   = (v, p = 2) =>  v < 0 ? 0 : v > 1 ? 1 : v ** p / (v ** p + (1 - v) ** p); 
 
  //==============================================================
  // main render function
  function update() {
    refreshFrames ++;
    if(!refereshSkip || (refereshSkip && refreshFrames % 8 === 0)){
      timer += 1000 / 60;
      ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
      ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
      if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight) {
        cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
        ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
      } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
      }
    
      // Move the map
      var speed = Math.sin(timer / 10000) * 8;
      worldX += Math.cos(worldDir) * speed;
      worldY += Math.sin(worldDir) * speed;
      if(dirChangeDelay-- <= 0) {
        dirChangeDelay = framesBetweenDirChange;
        prevDir = worldDir = prevDir + dirChange;
        dirChange = rand(-dirChangeMax , dirChangeMax);

      }
      worldDir = prevDir + (1-eCurve(dirChangeDelay / framesBetweenDirChange,3)) * dirChange;
    
      // Draw the map
      drawWorld();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}, 0);




/*===========================================================================
  CODE FROM HERE DOWN UNRELATED TO THE ANSWER
  
  ===========================================================================*/






const imageTools = (function() {
  // This interface is as is. No warenties no garenties, and NOT to be used comercialy
  var workImg, workImg1, keep; // for internal use
  keep = false;
  var tools = {
    canvas(width, height) { // create a blank image (canvas)
      var c = document.createElement("canvas");
      c.width = width;
      c.height = height;
      return c;
    },
    createImage: function(width, height) {
      var i = this.canvas(width, height);
      i.ctx = i.getContext("2d");
      return i;
    },
    drawSpriteQuick: function(image, spriteIndex, x, y) {
      var w, h, spr;
      spr = image.sprites[spriteIndex];
      w = spr.w;
      h = spr.h;
      ctx.drawImage(image, spr.x, spr.y, w, h, x, y, w, h);
    },
    line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
      ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    },
    circle(x, y, r) {
      ctx.moveTo(x + r, y);
      ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    },
  };
  return tools;
})();

const doFor = (count, cb) => {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < count && cb(i++) !== true);
}; // the ; after while loop is important don't remove
const randI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0;
const rand = (min = 1, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const seededRandom = (() => {
  var seed = 1;
  return {
    max: 2576436549074795,
    reseed(s) {
      seed = s
    },
    random() {
      return seed = ((8765432352450986 * seed) + 8507698654323524) % this.max
    }
  }
})();
const randSeed = (seed) => seededRandom.reseed(seed | 0);
const randSI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (seededRandom.random() % (max - min)) + min;
const randS = (min = 1, max = min + (min = 0)) => (seededRandom.random() / seededRandom.max) * (max - min) + min;
const tileSize = 64;
const tileCount = 7;

function drawGrass(ctx, c1, c2, c3) {
  const s = tileSize;
  const gs = s / (8 * c3);
  ctx.fillStyle = c1;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, s, s);

  ctx.strokeStyle = c2;
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.beginPath();
  doFor(s, i => {
    const x = rand(-gs, s + gs);
    const y = rand(-gs, s + gs);
    const x1 = rand(x - gs, x + gs);
    const y1 = rand(y - gs, y + gs);
    imageTools.line(x, y, x1, y1);
    imageTools.line(x + s, y, x1 + s, y1);
    imageTools.line(x - s, y, x1 - s, y1);
    imageTools.line(x, y + s, x1, y1 + s);
    imageTools.line(x, y - s, x1, y1 - s);
  })
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawTree(ctx, c1, c2, c3) {

  const seed = Date.now();
  const s = tileSize;
  const gs = s / 2;
  const gh = gs / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = c1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 4;
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 8;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 8;
  randSeed(seed);
  ctx.beginPath();
  doFor(18, i => {
    const ss = 1 - i / 18;
    imageTools.circle(randS(gs - gh * ss, gs + gh * ss), randS(gs - gh * ss, gs + gh * ss), randS(gh / 4, gh / 2));
  })
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.fillStyle = c2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = c3;
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.save();

  randSeed(seed);
  ctx.beginPath();
  doFor(18, i => {
    const ss = 1 - i / 18;
    imageTools.circle(randS(gs - gh * ss, gs + gh * ss) - 2, randS(gs - gh * ss, gs + gh * ss) - 2, randS(gh / 4, gh / 2) / 1.6);
  })
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();


}


const tileRenders = [
  (ctx) => {
    drawGrass(ctx, "#4C4", "#4F4", 1)
  },
  (ctx) => {
    drawGrass(ctx, "#644", "#844", 2)
  },
  (ctx) => {
    tileRenders[0](ctx);
    drawTree(ctx, "#480", "#8E0", "#7C0")
  },
  (ctx) => {
    tileRenders[1](ctx);
    drawTree(ctx, "#680", "#AE0", "#8C0")
  },
  (ctx) => {
    drawGrass(ctx, "#008", "#00A", 4)
  },
  (ctx) => {
    drawGrass(ctx, "#009", "#00C", 4)
  },
  (ctx) => {
    drawGrass(ctx, "#00B", "#00D", 4)
  },
]
const tileSet = imageTools.createImage(tileSize * tileCount, tileSize);
const ctxMain = ctx;
ctx = tileSet.ctx;
tileSet.sprites = [];
doFor(tileCount, i => {
  x = i * tileSize;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, 0);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, tileSize, tileSize);
  ctx.clip()
  if (tileRenders[i]) {
    tileRenders[i](ctx)
  }
  tileSet.sprites.push({
    x,
    y: 0,
    w: tileSize,
    h: tileSize
  });
  ctx.restore();
});
ctx = ctxMain;
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  color: white;
}
#pixAlignInfo {
  color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 4px;
}
#pixAlignInfo:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #0008;
  cursor: pointer;
}
body {
  background: #49c;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div>Hold left button to slow to 1/8th<br>
  <span id="pixAlignInfo">Click this button to toggle pixel alignment. Alignment is ON</span></div>
```

Comment: Hello. thanks for so big explanation. But I got confused. I created .json map in Tiled and I don't know how to draw it using your solution? Could you please help me? ]Game Code](https://github.com/danmoop/moople.js---html5-library/blob/master/Examples/Tilemap/public/js/game.js#L67)
||| [Folder with library and .json map](https://github.com/danmoop/moople.js---html5-library/tree/master/Examples/Tilemap/public/js)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I had a very quick look at the link, the tile map is similar to the answer. The first item in the JSON layers array `data` is the same as `tileMap` so set `tileMap = layers[0].data` then set `worldTileCount = 222`. The tiles are the same size 64*64. The only thing left is the tile sprites. Load the image, call it `tiles` and in `drawWorld` function replace `imageTools.drawSpriteQuick(.. `with `ctx.drawImage(tiles, (tindx % 15) * 64, (tindx / 15 | 0) * 64, 64, 64, (tx + x) * s, (ty + y) * s,64,64)`  The moople documentation is rather poor, maybe you should consider something like Phaser.js

Comment: Hello, I changed it, I can see my map but now camera isn't moving at all, and keyboatd input doesn't work like i don't type anything at all. No errors at the console

Comment: This works, but the movement seems quite jittery. How can the movement be made more smooth?

Comment: @kojow7 Please define "jittery" and "more smooth". If you mean frame rate low or skipping you will have to reduce the display area to match the device's capabilities. If you mean movement then change the algorithm (currently randomly moves the map). Algorithm is in function `update` under the comment `// Move the map`

Comment: @Blindman67 By jittery I mean that if it is moving up towards a specific point, during some of that movement it looks like it is panning straight to that point with no problem, but other portions of that movement it looks like it is experiencing a "tremor"-like (earthquake/shaking) effect. If I shrink the window it does seem a bit less noticeable, but still not competently gone. Is the randomness of the algorithm causing this or is it the frame rate?

Comment: @kojow7 I have updated the answer with more information regarding the jitter, why it is happening, and added some controls to demo to highlight the jitter and show what happens when pixel alignment, the main reason for jitter, is turned off.