# Draw tilemap only on visible canvas area - optimization

Tags: javascript, canvas

I just came up with idea on how to draw only the images that are within the canvas are (javascript tilemap game). however not sure if that is optimized enough as I though it would be. Any ideas on how to make it more optimized?

Currently I loop for Y and X using map array and then for every X in Y I use drawImage with position coordinates. I have put an if statement, right before it draws, to check if the current X and Y are within the canvas or not. If it is, it draws the image. Here is a bit of code that can show that and in a moment will give a link to test it.

```
            var mapArray=[

                [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,3],
                [3,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,3],
                [3,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,3],
                [3,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
            ];

// x= 22
// y= 15




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  // DRAW PLAYER

var player = new Object();
player.y = canvas.height/2-40;    //player position - middle of canvas - 40
player.x = canvas.width/2-40;     //player position - middle of canvas - 40
player.Width = 80;
player.Height = 80;
  player_image = new Image();
  player_image.src = 'http://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/horseright1.png';




function drawPlayer() {      // drawing the player
    context.beginPath();
    context.drawImage(player_image, player.x, player.y, player.Width, player.Height);
    context.closePath();
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------



      var updateX=(player.x-210);  // Starting point of canvas X
      var updateY=(player.y-160);  // Starting point of canvas Y
            var posX=updateX;
            var posY=updateY;




//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       //DRAW THE MAP AND THE PLAYER      

function drawMap() {

var posY = updateY;    // new Y coordinates for the map after movement


var grass = new Image();
var stone = new Image();
var black = new Image();
            grass.src= 'http://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/tile/grass.jpeg';
            stone.src = 'http://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/tile/sand.jpeg';
            black.src = 'http://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/tile/black.png';

   //---------------------------------------------------------
                    // Draw the map loop
            grass.onload = function (){
            stone.onload = function (){
            black.onload = function (){
            for(var i=0; i < mapArray.length; i++){
                for(var j=0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++){


   //=======================================================================   
            //CHECK IF X AND Y POSITIONS OF THE TILE ARE WITHIN THE CANVAS
   //=======================================================================
                    if(mapArray[i][j]==0){
               if (posY > canvasBegY && posY < canvasEndY && posX > canvasBegX && posX < canvasEndX){
                        context.drawImage(grass,posX, posY, 64, 64);   // Load image for grass "0"
                           }
                    }



                    if(mapArray[i][j]==1){
               if (posY > canvasBegY && posY < canvasEndY && posX > canvasBegX && posX < canvasEndX){
                        context.drawImage(stone,posX,posY,64,64);     // Load image for stone "1"
                           }
                    }



                    if(mapArray[i][j]==3){
               if (posY > canvasBegY && posY < canvasEndY && posX > canvasBegX && posX < canvasEndX){
                        context.drawImage(black,posX,posY,64,64);     // Load image for black "3"
                           }
                    }
     //=======================================================================

                    posX+=64;
                }
                posY+=64;
                posX=updateX;   // new X coordinates for the map after movement
   //---------------------------------------------------------
              drawPlayer();          // Draw the player
            }
        }
     }
    }
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It looks like it's simple enough and that is why I would like to check if there is anything you can think off that can optimize it more.

Here is a link to the whole thing to test it out:

https://jsfiddle.net/todorpet/cast5aq2/

Also, though about adding clearRect to the non-visible part around the canvas as the images. Should I add this as well ?

Comment: Cool! Yet I wouldn't look into improving clipping right now. :) How about creating the images just once, on app-load; and maybe throw in a switch statement and some "return"s, for cleaner code?

Using requestAnimationFame and looking for a way to keep track of passed time could be a worthwile next step, then? (You could even use that to implement an FPS counter!)

Comment: Was not sure about the clipping, though now I am sure and no need for it. Creating the images outside the tile map loop function is good idea, though I have to declare the src in it, otherwise it will draw them just one (will update that for sure). I am still newbie when it comes to canvas as I started using it about week or two ago and was not using much the switch statement there, but might do it very soon. Was thinking about requestAnimationFrame as well (have in the code as comment), but the character stats moving too slow depending on how loaded the browser is. Will look into the FTPS.Tnx

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/47019230/3877726

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 600,000fps not going to happen.

There is a major flaw in the code

Line 288

```
setInterval(gameLoop, 30);        // 30 milisec to draw next frame
```

This creates an interval event that is called every 30 ms. Because this is inside the function `gameLoop`, you are just creating more and more interval timers.

On the first call game loop is called ~30 times a second, on the next loop you add another interval, so now you have ~60 calls to game loop per second, the next call and you have 90, and now the extra calls start firing and the number of calls to `gameLoop` start to grow exponentially.

If the `gameLoop` function ran perfectly then within 1000ms (1 second) you would have ~20000 intervals each creating ~30 calls a second, that's ~600000 frames per second.

Obviously that cant happen, The interval between any two timer events is throttled by the browser, and the time that the game loop function takes to run limits the rate as well.

### To fix

You had it correct in the code 'requestAnimationFrame`

```
function gameLoop(){
   playerMovement();          //Check for movements
   drawMap();                 //Draw the map and the player

   /* NEVER use setInterval or setTimeout for animating anything!!! */
   //setInterval(gameLoop, 30);        // 30 milisec to draw next frame

   // use this. It will automatically slow down the frame rate to 30frames 
   // 20, 15, 10 and so on, per second if your render code is slow.
   requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

### To the tile map

Your function as I found it.

> ```
> function drawMap() {
>
>     var posY = updateY; // new Y coordinates for the map after movement
>
>
>     var grass = new Image();
>     var stone = new Image();
>     var black = new Image();
>     grass.src = 'http://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/tile/grass.jpeg';
>     stone.src = 'http://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/tile/sand.jpeg';
>     black.src = 'http://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/tile/black.png';
>
>     grass.onload = function () {
>         stone.onload = function () {
>             black.onload = function () {
>                 for (var i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
>                     for (var j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
>
>                         if (mapArray[i][j] == 0) {
>                             if (posY > canvasBegY && posY < canvasEndY && posX > canvasBegX && posX < canvasEndX) {
>                                 context.drawImage(grass, posX, posY, 64, 64); // Load image for grass "0"
>                             }
>                         }
>
>                         if (mapArray[i][j] == 1) {
>                             if (posY > canvasBegY && posY < canvasEndY && posX > canvasBegX && posX < canvasEndX) {
>                                 context.drawImage(stone, posX, posY, 64, 64); // Load image for stone "1"
>                             }
>                         }
>
>                         if (mapArray[i][j] == 3) {
>                             if (posY > canvasBegY && posY < canvasEndY && posX > canvasBegX && posX < canvasEndX) {
>                                 context.drawImage(black, posX, posY, 64, 64); // Load image for black "3"
>                             }
>                         }
>
>                         posX += 64;
>                     }
>                     posY += 64;
>                     posX = updateX; // new X coordinates for the map after movement
>                     drawPlayer(); // Draw the player
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

This is very bad, each frame you create a new set of images, then you add the `onload` only to the first image, when that image loads you add the `onload` event to the next image, and then the same for the third.

Not only is this very very slow and resource hungry, it also may not work randomly. Images will not load and fire the `onload` event in the same order as you create them, If the second image loads before the first its `onload` event is not set and thus will never fire, same for the third image.

### Load once.

To use resources for a game you load them all at the start of the game before any game plays (the loading screen)

As you are using a tile map to reference to images the best is to load the images into an array indexed to match the map.

```
const imageSrcDir = "http://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/tile/"
const tileImages = [];
function loadImages(images) {
    images.forEach(image => {
        const img = tileImages[image.mapIndex] = new Image();
        img.src = imageSrcDir + image.name;
    });
}
// load the images and add to the tileImage array
loadImages([
    { name : "grass.jpeg", mapIndex : 0 },
    { name : "stone.jpeg", mapIndex : 1 },
    { name : "black.png", mapIndex : 3 },
]);
```

### Player

You were rendering the player inside the second loop of the map rendering loops. That means you were rendering the player 15 times. No good. You should separate the different parts of the game. Draw the map, then the player as separate functions.

See example of how I deal with the player.

### Setup the map.

First flatten the map so you can access it quickly, and I have converted it to a string so it is easier to edit

```
const testMap = [
    "3333333333333333333333",
    "3000000000000000000003",
    "3000111000000011100003",
    "3011110000101111000013",
    "3010011100001001110003",
    "3000000000000000000003",
    "3000111000000011100003",
    "3011110000101111000013",
    "3010011100001001110003",
    "3000000000000000000003",
    "3000111000000011100003",
    "3011110000101111000013",
    "3010011100001001110003",
    "3000011000000001100003",
    "3333333333333333333333",
];
```

Function to create a map from the above type map. It get the width and height as well, and converts from string to number. You could use any character to represent different map bits.

```
function createMap(map){
    const newMap = {};
    newMap.width = map[0].length;
    newMap.height = map.length;
    newMap.array = new Uint8Array(newMap.width * newMap.height);
    var index = 0;
    for(const row of map){
         var i = 0;
         while(i < row.length){
             newMap.array[index++] = Number(row[i++]);
         }
    }
    return newMap;
}
const currentMap = createMap(testMap);
```

### The tiles

You need some info about the tiles

```
const tileWidth = 64;
const tileHeight = 64;
```

### Position the map

With the flattened map data you can draw the map, You will need to have a map position (the top right corner) that represents the view. You can get that from the player position, which should be in map coordinates.

```
var playerX = 6; // in tile coordinates 6.5 would be halfway to till 7
var playerY = 2;

var mapX = 0;  // the map position so that the player can be seen
var mapY = 0;


// get the map position
function getMapPosition(){
    // convert player to pixel pos
    var x = playerX * tileWidth;
    var y = playerY * tileHeight; 
    x -= canvas.width / 2;     // center on the canvas
    y -= canvas.heigth / 2;       
    mapX = x;
    mapY = y;
}
```

### Draw the map

There are some important parts. When you see `|0` that is the same as floor. eg `x = Math.floor(x`) is the same as `x = x | 0` or `x |= 0` This is much faster than floor.

The canvas 2D renderer has some flaws that you must avoid. When you draw tiles you need to make sure that they are aligned to the canvas pixels, if not you end up will flickering seams between tiles as the map moves.

This is fixed in the line that sets the transform.

ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -mapX | 0, -mapY | 0);

the `mapX` and `mapY` are negated and floored. The floor aligns the map to the pixels ensuring there are no seams.

Once this function is called the canvas transform is set to map coordinates. You then draw all other game object at their map coordinates not the canvas coordinates, making drawing objects in the game a lot easier.

```
function drawMap(map) {
    const w = map.width; // get the width of the tile array
    const mArray = map.array;
    const tx = mapX / tileWidth | 0; // get the top left tile
    const ty = mapY / tileHeight | 0;
    const tW = (canvas.width / tileWidth | 0) + 2; // get the number of tiles to fit canvas
    const tH = (canvas.height / tileHeight | 0) + 2;
    // set the location via the transform
    // From here on you draw all the game items relative to the map not the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -mapX | 0, -mapY | 0);

    // Draw the tiles if tile pos is off map draw black tile
    for (var y = 0; y < tH; y += 1) {
        for (var x = 0; x < tW; x += 1) {
            const i = tx + x + (ty + y) * w;
            const tileIndex = mArray[i] === undefined ? 3 : mArray[i]; // if outside map draw black tile
            ctx.drawImage(tileImages[tileIndex], (tx + x) * tileWidth, (ty + y) * tileHeight);
        }
    }

}
```

So that is how to draw a tile map, well one way to draw a tile map.

### Example

The snippet below shows it all put together with your character, use arrow keys to move.

There are a few minor changes from the above.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const imageSrcDir = "http://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/tile/"
const tileImages = [];

requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  // start it after all code below has run
function mainLoop(){
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  
  //control the player
  if(keys.ArrowUp){
      player.y -= 0.1;
  }
  if(keys.ArrowDown){
      player.y += 0.1;
  }
  if(keys.ArrowLeft){
      player.x -= 0.1;
  }
  if(keys.ArrowRight){
      player.x += 0.1;
  }
  // Make sure the player stays on the mapo
  if(player.x < 2){ player.x = 2 }
  if(player.y < 2){ player.y = 2 }
  if(player.x >= currentMap.width-2){ player.x = currentMap.width-2}
  if(player.y >= currentMap.height-2){ player.y = currentMap.height-2}
  
  
  getMapPosition();
  drawMap(currentMap);
  player.draw();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

}

function loadImages(images) {
  images.forEach(image => {
    const img = tileImages[image.mapIndex] = new Image();
    img.src = imageSrcDir + image.name;
  });
}
// load the images and add to the tileImage array
loadImages([{
    name: "grass.jpeg",
    mapIndex: 0
  },
  {
    name: "sand.jpeg",
    mapIndex: 1
  },
  {
    name: "black.png",
    mapIndex: 3
  },
]);

const player = {
  x: 6,
  y: 2,
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  image: (() => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/horseright1.png";
    return img;
  })(),
  draw(){
     ctx.drawImage(player.image,player.x * tileWidth - player.width / 2, player.y * tileHeight - player.height / 2);  
  },
};



const testMap = [
  "3333333333333333333333",
  "3000000000000000000003",
  "3000111000000011100003",
  "3011110000101111000013",
  "3010011100001001110003",
  "3000000000000000000003",
  "3000111000000011100003",
  "3011110000101111000013",
  "3010011100001001110003",
  "3000000000000000000003",
  "3000111000000011100003",
  "3011110000101111000013",
  "3010011100001001110003",
  "3000011000000001100003",
  "3333333333333333333333",
];

// function to create a map from the above type map 
function createMap(map) {
  const newMap = {};
  newMap.width = map[0].length;
  newMap.height = map.length;
  newMap.array = new Uint8Array(newMap.width * newMap.height);
  var index = 0;
  for (const row of map) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < row.length) {
      newMap.array[index++] = Number(row[i++]);
    }
  }
  return newMap;
}
const currentMap = createMap(testMap);

const tileWidth = 64;
const tileHeight = 64;


var mapX = 0; // the map position so that the player can be seen
var mapY = 0;


// get the map position
function getMapPosition() {
  // convert player to pixel pos
  var x = player.x * tileWidth + player.width / 2;
  var y = player.y * tileHeight + player.height / 2;
  x -= canvas.width / 2; // center on the canvas
  y -= canvas.height / 2;
  mapX = x;
  mapY = y;
}




function drawMap(map) {
  const w = map.width; // get the width of the tile array
  const mArray = map.array;
  const tx = mapX / tileWidth | 0; // get the top left tile
  const ty = mapY / tileHeight | 0;
  const tW = (canvas.width / tileWidth | 0) + 2; // get the number of tiles to fit canvas
  const tH = (canvas.height / tileHeight | 0) + 2;
  // set the location via the transform
  // From here on you draw all the game items relative to the map not the canvas
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -mapX | 0, -mapY | 0);

  // Draw the tiles if tile pos is off map draw black tile
  for (var y = 0; y < tH; y += 1) {
    for (var x = 0; x < tW; x += 1) {
      const rx = tx + x;  // get tile real pos
      const ry = ty + y;
      var tileIndex;
      if(rx < 0 || rx >= w){
          tileIndex = 3; // black if off map
      }else{
          const i = rx + ry * w;
          tileIndex = mArray[i] === undefined ? 3 : mArray[i]; // if outside map draw black tile
      }
      ctx.drawImage(tileImages[tileIndex], rx * tileWidth, ry * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight);
    }
  }

}


const keys = {
    ArrowUp : false,
    ArrowDown : false,
    ArrowLeft : false,
    ArrowRight : false,
};
function keyEvents(e){
    if(keys[e.code] !== undefined){
        keys[e.code] = e.type === "keydown";
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
addEventListener("keyup", keyEvents);
addEventListener("keydown", keyEvents);
window.focus();
```

```html
Arrow keys to move.
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Nice! I already took care of some of the things mentioned - like loading the images in a function is really a bad thing. And thank you for the example on how to would have drawn the map and player as I honestly though that all the drawing and players etc. should go under the gameLoop. That helped big time!